# How to find the result of first thread that finishes successfully in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose there are multiple threads trying to find a value, whichever thread finds it first should send the output to the main thread and all other threads should be terminated.
Example -

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some long task here, returns int value
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         // initialize multiple worker threads here
         // then get result from the thread that completes first
    }
}
```

I looked into docs and found invokeAny [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) but this will return the result of any thread that has been completed successfully and not necessarily the first one.

Comment: Ideally you would not manage threads that low level yourself but use the available high level APIs, such as `Executors`, `CompletableFuture`s and similar. Then this is fairly simple to realize... For example `CompletableFuture.anyOf(...)` and then, once that finishes, `future.cancel(true)` all the others.

Comment: What is the 'result' of the thread? Threads have no stati nor even exit codes.

Comment: Oh, maybe I should use Callable instead of Runnable but how will I get the result from the first thread that finished.

Comment: Have a look at [CompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andy Turner said, use a `CompletionService`:

```
    public static class WorkerThread implements Callable<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(10000);
            try {
                System.out.println("I will cost " + nextInt + " ms to finish job.--" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(nextInt);
            } catch (InterruptedException ite) {
                System.out.println("I am interrupted.--" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return -1;
            }
            System.out.println("I am finish.--" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return nextInt;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int nums = 3;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nums);
        CompletionService<Integer> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
        while (nums-- > 0) {
            completionService.submit(new WorkerThread());
        }
        Integer firstValue = completionService.take().get();
        System.out.println("FirstValue is " + firstValue);
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
```

And you can see in output, only one thread will complete the job (Because only call `completionService#take` once
), other threads will be interrupted and exit
:

```
I will cost 8943 ms to finish job.--pool-1-thread-1
I will cost 9020 ms to finish job.--pool-1-thread-2
I will cost 5025 ms to finish job.--pool-1-thread-3
I am finish.--pool-1-thread-3
FirstValue is 5025
I am interrupted.--pool-1-thread-1
I am interrupted.--pool-1-thread-2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for achieving this.

Create CountDownLatch object with count = 1.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

Use ExecutorService pool to execute the threads and pass the latch in all the threads.

```
workerThreadPool.execute(new WorkerThread(latch));
```

Wait for any thread to complete it's operation.

```
latch.await();
```

In the finally block of the thread run, shutdown the latch.

```
latch.countDown();
```

As soon as any thread countDown's the latch, the threadpool will stop all the other threads and shutdown.

```
workerThreadPool.shutdownNow();
```

The complete example would be below.

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class WorkerThread implements Runnable
{

    CountDownLatch _latch;

    public WorkerThread(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        _latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // some long task here, returns int value
            System.out.println("In thread1 " + this.toString());
            sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("thread1 interupted");
        }
        finally
        {

            System.out.println("Finished1 " + this.toString());
            _latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}

class WorkerThread2 implements Runnable
{

    CountDownLatch _latch;

    public WorkerThread2(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        _latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // some long task here, returns int value
            System.out.println("In thread2 " + this.toString());
            sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("thread2 interupted");
        }
        finally
        {

            System.out.println("Finished2 " + this.toString());
            _latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ExecutorService workerThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        workerThreadPool.execute(new WorkerThread(latch));
        workerThreadPool.execute(new WorkerThread2(latch));

        latch.await();

        workerThreadPool.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You -could- pass a reference to the Thread where the Thread can send its results. But you'd better follow advice in the other answers and use a better API for this :)

```
public static void main(//) {

    ResultConsumer r = new ResultConsumer();
    ... create and start worker threads
}


public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    public WorkerThread ( ResultConsumer r ) {
         this.r=r
    }
     @Override
    public void run() {
        // some long task here, returns int value
        r.sendResult(....)
    }
}
```